# Calling a C function from Objective-C and passing specific arguments

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, parameter-passing

I have to implement a C function that will be called from an Objective-C App on which I have no control.

The function will receive a `CVImageBufferRef` struct and will return an `NSMutableArray` of structs, containing a few integers and an `NSString`.

I have a few questions about this.

- What C headers should I include for successful compilation ? (getting the declarations of the `CV...` functions and `NS...` types)
- How do I handle the `NSMutableArray` from C to add elements and return it ?
- How do I fill the `NSString`s from C ?

Any help is welcome.

---

**Update:**

A pure C wrapper is no more envisioned. Now my question reduces to how to interface Objective-C to Objective-C++ and handle the specific data types I mentioned. And what does it mean to toll-free bridge concretely ?

Comment: Can I frame-challenge this? Since you're apparently implementing an Objective-C API, why not write an Objective-C function? Anyway, NSMutableArray is toll-free bridged with CFMutableArrayRef, and NSString with CFStringRef. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html

Comment: @TurePålsson: sorry, I have no Objective- culture, and I find the Apple documentation very terse. So I can't appraise the relevance of your comment (which adds a layer of puzzleness). I don't know about the compatibility of Objective-C and standard C (to tell you more, the C function will wrap C++ code).

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the `C++` with `Objective-C++`? The three (Obj-C, C, and C++) are very compatible and the implementation is more of a matter of the requirements. Wrapping is not even required if you put the code at the top of the `Obj-C` and include the imports. Maybe show some code and then it might be more clear what you are actually requiring.

Comment: @ILI: I have no control on such design decisions.

Comment: I don't think you can import <Foundation/Foundation.h> in a C file - which is necessary to use objective-c object (as NSString or NSMutableArray) however. It should be a .m file instead but containing only C codes. Otherwise you should import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h> and replace objective-c objects by their core foundation counterpart (CFString or CFMutableArray) which would be possible in a pure C file.

Comment: @dspr: interesting. But can C code handle those classes ? I might be asking impossible things.

Comment: Yes in a .m file for Foundation (but not in a .c file - this the impossible part). Yes in both cases for CoreFoundation.

Comment: @dspr: thanks, I guess that I need to mature this a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay away from Objective-C:

- The Core Video stuff seems to be C (I haven't looked very closely) so `#include <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>` should have you covered.
- For `NSString` and `NSMutableArray`, use their toll-free bridged CoreFoundation counterparts. Toll-free bridgning means that a C type can be used interchangeably with an Objective-C type. Read all about it at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html .

Comment: Thanks, this goes in the way that I need. But the page you linked to is shockingly void about the Core Foundation types. (And no mention of an include file.)